# Is the order of columns in a clustered index important?

Tags: index-tuning, clustered-index, teradata

Does it matters which field I specify first in the index?

would

```
CREATE SET TABLE my_table
(   
        validity_date DATE
    ,   branch_id SMALLINT 
    ,   account_class_id BYTEINT
    ,   catalog_id INTEGER
    ,   No_events FLOAT
)
PRIMARY INDEX (validity_date, branch_id);
```

be treated by the server same as

```
CREATE SET TABLE my_table
(   
        validity_date DATE
    ,   branch_id SMALLINT 
    ,   account_class_id BYTEINT
    ,   catalog_id INTEGER
    ,   No_events FLOAT
)
PRIMARY INDEX (branch_id, validity_date);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordering of the columns defined in the index *generally* represents the combinations of all subsets of predicates covered by that index.

For example, an index on the columns `(Column1, Column2)` will cover predicates, such as a `WHERE` clause, that filter on `Column1` and `Column2` in the same clause, or only `Column1` in that clause. It will not normally cover `Column2` by itself in that clause, and therefore that index is not applicable to that predicate clause.

Conversely if you reversed the order that you defined the columns of that index for, such that it's definition was `(Column2, Column1)`, then it would cover `Column2` by itself, or `Column1` and `Column2` in the same predicate clause. But then it would not cover `Column1` by itself in that clause.

Adding the caveat to my above answer that with Teradata there is a type of index known as a **hash index** which sounds like it shouldn't matter what order the columns are defined in, **but** that type of index is only applicable to predicates that **exactly** match in columns to whichever columns are hashed in the index. So it sounds like it depends on which type of index is used, as discussed in [their docs](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/e79ET77%7ENzPDz%7EYkinj44w/cPHwOKGrQgx7W_O2upZV1Q).

Comment: Please note that the question is tagged with [tag:teradata]. I'm no expert at all with Teradata but I htink dnoeth's answer is correct.

Comment: Thanx, that explanation gives some clarity to my user experience, However it is still not fully clear to me. Because, on same data set, using only column2 predicate gave me better results in (column2, column1) index rather then (column1, column2) index. But using only column2 predicate in (column1, column2) index gave me better results then using no index at all. Therefore, it seems, in contrast with other stated comments and answers here, both parts of the index are used to avoid full scan, the first one is just more efficient for some reason.

Comment: @EliyArlev While my answer is typically true of most modern relational database management systems, I can't say specifically for Teradata what distinct differences there might be. I did some additional research the other day and it does sound like in some cases (depending on the type of index used) the order of the columns might not matter because Teradata has a hash index. I don't believe this is always the type of index used though, and what I wrote still holds true in some cases. Regarding the second case you mentioned, it depends, but it's possible an index scan was still most optimal.

Comment: Teradata's indexes are mostly hash-based. The so-called *Primary Index* is exactly the same as *partition by hash* in other DBMSes. If using a single column of a multi-column PI shows "better results" it can't be because of index usage. Checking the resource usage data (DBQL/QueryLog) will reveal this.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no difference at all in Teradata. The PI is hash-based, both columns must be used in a Where- or Join-condition to allow index-based access.